# Cast uniqueidentifier to binary

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, casting

how can i Cast uniqueidentifier to binary in Sql?
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically you will need to use CAST in SQL server -

```
DECLARE @program_guid uniqueidentifier, @program_binary binary(16)
--
SELECT @program_guid = '327EBEA7-3D4E-473A-8D72-7CB68AB51F73'
SELECT @program_binary = CAST(@program_guid AS binary(16))
```